# Cannot receive catch-all email from some servers

Tags: email, dns, smtp

For years I have been using the email catch-all feature to track how companies treat my email adress, i.e. I will be able to detect if they sell my email and can confront them or add a filter that tags those emails as spam.
That means that I use an email adress like myname.acme@foo.com as email address at the company acme. Since I have used this for many years I probably have more than 100 email addresses like this.

But lately I have noticed that expected emails from some email servers never arrive to me, and they do not arrive in the spam folder. If I send an email to the same address manually, it arrives as it should. It is typically servers that have some internal support system at a large company that can send email notifications when something new has happened.

So my question is how I can solve this?
The big companies are typically to large to investigate this kind of issues for me, it is a domain that I use for personal use.
Is the sending email server aware that the email address is a catch-all address instead of a "proper" email address?

I have SPF, DKIM, DMARC setup for the domain, but I assume that this should only affect emails coming from my domain, not the email coming to my domain. Is this correct?
It is kind of difficult to check the headers on emails that I do not receive...

The domain is hosted by mydomain.com which seem to use email servers from eigbox.net. I tried to contact support at mydomain.com, but they didn't understand the problem.

Comment: Do you use an unusual format for the local-part@ of your email addresses? Do your mail server's logs have any mentions whatsoever of the sender attempting to deliver the mail?

Comment: Nothing strange in the local part, like for this site I would use something like bimme.superuser@foo.com. Unfortunately I do not have full access to the server so I can only see successful attempts.